# EF Code First: Creating Customer, Item and Order relationship using poco

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1, code-first, poco

I am trying to create 3 tables represented by pocos for use in code first.

The tables are customer, item and orders. (i presume the orders is a good naming convetion? or should i use customitem, or customeritem?)

I have created a customer table with an Id and things like Name, Address

I have created an item table with an Id and things like itemname and price.

Now i need to create a 3rd table which will hold the number of items a customer has purchased. I have an Id so i need to create 2 foreign keys (int) 1 called CustomerId and the other called ItemId - is this correct?

Then i need to create a navigation property from customers so i can see all the items that the customers has purchased

and navigation property for an item so you can see which customers has purchased that item

I am a little lost of how to do this

Does anyone have an example or can help me?

I presume its a standard question, how to create customers and items and store who purchased what but i can't seem to find any tutorials

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the third table,`Entity framework` will create the third table automatically and the relationship will be managed internally.Only you have to put the `Principal and dependent` in the code using `Navigation Properties.`

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Items = new HashSet<Item>();
    }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

 public partial class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int CustomerCustomerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Thus , you can establish the relationship between the two tables, `customer` and `item`. But if you want to add some *descriptive attributes* to the relation , then you should go creating new table in entity framework which will include foreign keys from both `Customer` and `Item` classes and your additional discriptive attributes like `PurchaseDate` etc

Comment: Thanks for the comment, ah i didn't realize this. But what if i need the 3rd table? You see i need to provide myself with 3 services, for Customer, Item and Orders..  and 3 repositories for each table. Do you have a small example or can you elaborate a little more? thanks again

Comment: you want one-to many relationship between customer and items ...right ?

Comment: exactly 1 customer can have many items...  and 1 item could have been bought by many customers.

Comment: Hi, thats great! Just what i needed, 1 problem i see is i can´t store when the Item was bought by the customer, I think this is why i may need 3 tables?   Sorry, is this possible with the above model?

Comment: Surely, you can store and with this model only. You will simply need to pass the user info along.

Comment: so i create a customer ... Customer customer = new Customer(); and i populate the values, then in the navigation property i use add on the prop Items?? but where would i add the Date of Purchase  without changing the model??  I dont want add the date of purchase in items or customer.. because if i get GetCustomers or GetItems, I am not interested in Orders.... Am i right here?  Or am i completely off track?

Comment: @Martin Please accept as answer as your problem in question is solved.